# Can Iask questions here about other planets like Mars?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Are questions applicable about Mars here on Earth Science? Can this be used like a Planet Science as well as Earth Science?

Answer (score -2):

### No.

Those sort of questions would be more suitable for [astronomy.se](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/).